# Certain cells do not 'Work' in formulas

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I'll just dive right in. A cell(s) won't work in a formula, for whatever reason. I've tried everything, including duplicating the data to a new section in the spreadsheet, resetting the font/conditional formatting/size etc; checked to see if there are any spaces; rewriting the data etc.

Now obviously it could be an error on my behalf, with respects to writing in the function, so I tried rewriting the entire formula, in a different section, with the same data and got the expected results. I then copied and pasted the data/formula next to each other to compare the difference, there is none whatsoever. I just do not know what's wrong.

There's a lot of data in the spreadsheet, so I can't just rewrite all the data (I can't copy and paste them either as doing so carries over whatever is causing the problem into the other spreadsheet).
Below is a spreadsheet containing an example:

Stack Exchange Example Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ePT8MmY48TUTaIjwbX4XftEatZ76qbh7QUYpq1fwI-c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How about sharing the formula?

Comment: Which cell won't work?

Comment: Oh, the formulas in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Don't rely on links. Questions should be self-contained. A link is great for _supplemental_ information, but a potential answerer shouldn't _need_ to follow the link to offer an answer. Worse, a future reader shouldn't have to follow a link to see if they're having the same problem. When the link stops working, there's very little value to the question.

Answer (score 0):

well if I understand... select cell **D2** or whole column **D** and then press that `"123"` icon and select Auto or Number

[image]

`=SUMIF` works only with numbers that are formatted as numbers and not numbers that are formatted as text